# For every code change need to export the war and restart the server

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, jboss, struts

I am working in a GWT-Struts-Hibernate project. Whenever I changed any GWT code, it will reflect in Dev mode. But Whenever I changed any Struts or Hibernate related code, I need to stop the server and export the war to Jboss and then start the server. This eats lots of my working time.

Is there any alternative process for this? We are using Jboss 4.2.3.GA server.

Comment: Look into JBoss hot deployment for Hibernate

Comment: also maybe look into using Waratek JVM which allows virtualization, stopping and starting of applications a CLI - cool technology

Answer (score 0):

I know in JBoss 7, you can update your deployment-scanner in the standalone.xml configuration file and modify like this `auto-deploy-exploded=true`.

Of course, you can change this from admin console.